# How do I make the right hand move up and then wave?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to get the right hand of my CSS animation to move up and then wave, how do I accomplish that using keyframes in CSS? Btw don't run the code snippet in here try running it in a separate file in google chrome for it to show up properly. I also want it to be neat so that the arm is still attached to the shirt when it waves and the arm and sleeve should be moving at the same pace, thanks for the help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Waving Person</title>
 <style>
 body{
  
  background-color:#F8FF09;
  overflow-x:hidden;
 }
 .face{
  width:94px;
  height:94px;
  border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
  background-color:#ffecb3;
  position:absolute;
  top:25.2%;
  left:46%;
  
 }
 .h1{
  width:105px; 
     height:35px; 
     background:saddlebrown;
     border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:24.5%;
 left:45.5%;
 
 }
 .h2{
   height:45px;
     width:75px;
     border-radius: 45px;
     background:saddlebrown;
  position:absolute;
  top:18.5%;
 left:46.3%;
 }
 .eye1{
  background-color:white;
  border-radius:50%;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:30.7%;
  left:46.9%;
  
 }
 .eye2{
  background-color:white;
  border-radius:50%;
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:30.7%;
  left:50.1%;
 }
 .eyeball,.eyeball2{
  height: 13px;
        width: 13px;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
 }
 .eyeball{
  top:31.2%;
  left:47.2%;
 }
 .eyeball2{
  top:31.2%;
  left:50.3%;
 }
 .d1,.d2{
  width:6px;
        height: 6px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: white;
  position:absolute;
 }
 .d1{
  top:31.2%;
  left:47.2%;
 }
 .d2{
  top:31.2%;
  left:50.8%;
 }
 .mouth{
   width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background:red;
            -webkit-border-radius: 20px 0px;
            border-radius: 20px 0px;
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            position: relative;
   left:649px;
  top:220px;
 }
.b1,.b2{
 background-color:#ffb3b3;
 width:10px;
 height:5px;
 border-radius:50%;
 position:relative;
}
.b1{
 left:625px;
 top:202px;
}
.b2{
 left:685px;
 top:197px;
 
}
.neck1{
 width:20px;
     height:25px;
     background-color:#ffecb3;
  position:relative;
  left:650px;
  top:220px;
}

.neck2{
 border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
 height:25px;
 width:45px;
 background-color:#ffecb3;
 position:relative;
    left:637px;
  top:220px;
}

.e1,.e2,.e3,.e4,.e5,.e6{
 background-color:black;
 width:10px;
    height:1.1px;
 transform:rotate(85deg);
 position:relative;
 
}
.e1{
 left:622.2px;
 top:114px;
}
.e2{
 left:628.2px;
 top:113px;
}
.e3{
 left:635.2px;
 top:113px;
}
.e4{
 left:666px;
 top:112px;
}
.e5{
 left:673px;
 top:109px;
}
.e6{
 left:679px;
 top:110px;
}
.t1{
 width:80px;
 height: 120px;
      background-color:crimson;
     border-radius: 15px;
 position:relative; 
    left:625px;
  top:190px;
  z-index:-1;
  animation:change 2s infinite;
}
.t2{
 border-bottom: 70px solid crimson;
 border-left: 35px solid transparent;
 border-right: 40px solid transparent;
 border-radius:15px;
 height: 0;
 width: 125px;
 position:relative;
 left:570px;
 top:170px;
 
}
.belt{
 position:relative;
 left:625px;
 top:65px;
}
.hand1{
 position: relative;
            background-color: #ffecb3;
            height: 100px;
            width: 20px;
            border-radius:10px;
            position:relative;
   left:595px;
   bottom:50px;
            transform: rotate(25deg);
}
.s1{
 border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
 background-color:crimson;
 height:90px;
 width:20px;
 transform:rotate(25deg);
 position:relative;
 left:603px;
 bottom:260px;
 
}
.hand2{
 position: relative;
            background-color: #ffecb3;
            height: 100px;
            width: 20px;
            border-radius:10px;
            position:relative;
   left:715px;
   bottom:155px;
            transform:rotate(-25deg);
   
}
.s2{
 border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
 background-color:crimson;
 height:90px;
 width:20px;
 transform:rotate(-25deg);
 position:relative;
 left:707px;
 bottom:357px;
 
}

 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="face"></div>
<div class="h1"></div>
<div class="h2"></div>
<div class="eye1"></div>
<div class="eye2"></div>
<div class="eyeball"></div>
<div class="eyeball2"></div>
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
<div class="mouth"></div>
<div class="teeth"></div>
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="neck1"></div>
<div class="neck2"></div>
<div class="e1"></div>
<div class="e2"></div>
<div class="e3"></div>
<div class="e4"></div>
<div class="e5"></div>
<div class="e6"></div>
<div class="t1"></div>
<div class="t2"></div>
<div class="belt">
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/2qCZQJv/5-2-belt-png-hd-thumb.png width="100px" height="80px""></div>
<div class="hand1"></div>
<div class="hand2"></div>
<div class="s1"></div>
<div class="s2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i can't see any animation related code into your snippet. What have you tried to accomplish this ?

Comment: um sorry but I've tried it on another fiddle but it seems incomplete

Comment: @akshaykishore click "full screen" after clicking on run code snippet to see the complete code.